# floating pie() in plotrix package in R (adjusting the opening & closing pattern)

Tags: r, plot

**Background:**

Presently, my "floating.pie" by **plotrix package** using:

```
plot(1:10,ty="n")

library(plotrix)

floating.pie(3, 8,c(.8, .2), 200 , 1, col=c("maroon","white"), lwd=2)
```

looks like this:

[image]

**QUESTION:** I was wondering if there might be an argument or a way so that floating pie **ALWAYS** looks downwards (always making a **"V" or "/\"** shape)?

**For example,** the above floating.pie **becomes like this:**

[image]

Comment: check out the `startpos` argument, e.g. `startpos=-pi/3` (by trial and error). Might be hard to have it happen automatically for all possible data sets ...

Comment: @BenBolker, will do thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can obtain the exact value of `startpos` as

```
startpos = (3*pi/2) + #Start at 3*pi/2 (facing generally downward)
           (0.2*2*pi/2) #Add half of the angle assigned for smaller value

#Then plot
plot(1:10,ty="n")
floating.pie(3, 8,c(.8, .2), 200 , 1, col=c("maroon","white"), lwd=2, startpos = startpos )
```